# Does anyone have a working trivial example of a Dockerfile & command line that mount an external directory from linux into the docker image?

Tags: docker

All I'm looking for is a Dockerfile & docker build+run commands on linux  to view /var/tmp via a mount point within the container. The issues here are all complicated cases or involve OS/X & Windows or trying to do more than simply mount a volume. I my case I've simply tried to mount /var/tmp onto
/foobar of a busybox image, run a container with the image, and use "ls /foobar" to see the contents.

Running "Docker version 1.6.1, build 97cd073" on linux 4.0.1 w/ aufs
using a local repostory.

http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/

Notes that:

```
Mount a Host Directory as a Data Volume

In addition to creating a volume using the 
-v flag you can also mount a directory from 
your Docker daemon's host into a container.

<snip>

$ sudo docker run -d -P --name web -v /src/webapp:/opt/webapp 
training/webapp python app.py

This will mount the host directory, /src/webapp, 
into the container at /opt/webapp.

    Note: If the path /opt/webapp already exists 
    inside the container's image, its contents 
    will be replaced by the contents of 
    /src/webapp on the host to stay consistent 
    with the expected behavior of mount

This is very useful for testing, for example we can mount our source 
code inside the container and see our application at work as we change 
the source code. The directory on the host must be specified as an 
absolute path and if the directory doesn't exist Docker will 
automatically create it for you.
```

I'm using a local repository that acquires its "/data" directory
via the "-v" switch to docker run:

```
docker run -d -p 5000 \
-v '/var/lib/docker/registry:/data/registry/storage' \
'kampka/registry';
```

This seems to work as the hosts's /var/lib/docker/registry directory
gets entries added to it.

So I try a simple test for myself: build a minimal copy of busybox
with access to /var/tmp on the host system.

```
FROM        localhost:5000/lembark/busybox
MAINTAINER  lembark@wrkhors.com

VOLUME  [ "/foobar" ]

ENV     PATH /bin
WORKDIR /

ENTRYPOINT  [ "/bin/sh" ]
```

At that point running "docker build" executes the VOLUME command, but does not create the mount point:

```
$ docker build --tag="localhost:5000/lembark/hak" . ;

Sending build context to Docker daemon  7.68 kB
Sending build context to Docker daemon
Step 0 : FROM localhost:5000/lembark/busybox
 ---> c1a1f5abbf79
Step 1 : MAINTAINER lembark@wrkhors.com
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b46677881767
Step 2 : VOLUME /foobar
 ---> Running in 7127bdbcfb56
 ---> bcf9c3f1c441
Removing intermediate container 7127bdbcfb56
Step 3 : ENV PATH /bin
 ---> Running in 89f92c815860
 ---> 780fea54a67f
Removing intermediate container 89f92c815860
Step 4 : WORKDIR /
 ---> Running in aa3871c408a1
 ---> 403190e9415b
Removing intermediate container aa3871c408a1
Step 5 : ENTRYPOINT /bin/sh
 ---> Running in 4850561f7ebd
 ---> 77c32530b4a9
Removing intermediate container 4850561f7ebd
Successfully built 77c32530b4a9
```

The "VOLUME /foobar" in Step 2 seems to indicate that a mount point
should be available at runtime.

At that point using either of

```
docker run --rm -t -i                     localhost:5000/lembark/hak;
docker run --rm -t -i -v /foobar          localhost:5000/lembark/hak;
docker run --rm -t -i -v /var/tmp:/foobar localhost:5000/lembark/hak;
```

leaves me with:

```
# ls -al /foobar
ls: /foobar: No such file or directory
```

Adding a mkdir before the VOLUME leaves me with a /foobar
directory with an anonymous volume, not the mapping from /var/tmp:

```
...

RUN     [ "mkdir", "/foobar" ]
VOLUME  [ "/foobar" ]
```

or

```
# made a local ./foobar directory, added that to the image.

COPY    [ "foobar", "/foobar" ]
```

Bofh of these leave with /foobar, but no way to map any external
directory to it. Instead I keep getting anonymous volumes:

```
 # mount | grep foobar;
 /dev/mapper/vg00-var--lib on /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/dd12f3e11a6fcb88627412a041b7c910e4d32dc1bf0c15330899036c59d7b3d9/foobar type xfs (rw,noatime,nodiratime,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=256k,logdev=/dev/vg02/var-lib-extlog,noquota)
```

No combination with or without each of mkdir, VOLUME, COPY, or -v leaves me viewing /var/tmp undef /foobar.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM busybox:latest
VOLUME /foo/bar
```

*Command*

```
$ docker build -t bb .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Sending build context to Docker daemon
Step 0 : FROM busybox:latest
 ---> 8c2e06607696
Step 1 : VOLUME /foo/bar
 ---> Running in a94615dd3353
 ---> fa500ba91831
Successfully built fa500ba91831
$ docker run -it -v /tmp:/foobar bb ls /foobar
[contents of my /tmp directory]
```

Note that you don't need the `VOLUME` command to do this. `docker run -it -v /tmp:/foobar busybox:latest ls /foobar` works just as well.

Comment: Trying that here gets me "no such file or directory" for the mounted volume.

`FROM        localhost:5000/lembark/busybox
VOLUME      /var/tmp
MAINTAINER  lembark@wrkhors.com
 $ ./build
Sending build context to Docker daemon 6.656 kB
Sending build context to Docker daemon
...
Step 1 : VOLUME /var/tmp
 ---> Running in bebc1b347b4e
 ---> 328a76d7eee3
...
Successfully built 8d8f2c71aae3
 $ docker run -v /var/tmp:/var/tmp localhost:5000/lembark/frobnicate ls  /var/tmp
ls: /var/tmp: No such file or directory
`

Comment: Adding a "mkdir","/va/rtmp" to the Dockerfile leaves me with anonymous storage for the volume, not a view of /var/tmp.

Comment: Do you actually have a /var/tmp on your local machine? Is it a normal directory that's accessible?

Comment: Yes. Currently mounted w/ mods 01777.

Comment: Yes. /var/tmp is mounted w/ mods 01777 and has contents; /lib64 (the original directory I've tried mounting) has mods 02775 and is populated.

`$ ls -ld /var/tmp;
drwxrwxrwt 21 root root 880 Jun  3 04:05 /var/tmp

$ ls /var/tmp|head -2
15PvaS0xyv
23611
'

Answer (score 0):

I did the same as @Nathaniel Waisbrot.

```
vagrant@vagrant:/code/busybox$ ls
Dockerfile
vagrant@vagrant:/code/busybox$ docker build -t busybox:0.0.1 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 9.216 kB
Sending build context to Docker daemon
Step 0 : FROM busybox:latest
---> 8c2e06607696
Step 1 : VOLUME /foobar
---> Running in 0b99eac833aa
---> a93b5ae5de5f
Removing intermediate container 0b99eac833aa
Successfully built a93b5ae5de5f
vagrant@vagrant:/code/busybox$ docker run -i -v /code/busybox/:/foobar busybox:0.0.1 ls /foobar
Dockerfile
vagrant@vagrant:/code/busybox$
```

Here is the Dockerfile I used to build the image.

```
FROM        busybox:latest

VOLUME  [ "/foobar" ]
```

Here you can see that I list my `/code/busybox` directory to show you the files in it.
Then I build the image.
Then I run the image and map my `/code/busybox` directory the images `/foobar` directory with `-v /code/busybox:/foobar`.
I then execute the image I built with the ls command and the directory I want to list `ls /foobar`.
The results are printed to the console.

Just to be clear I think there are a few items wrong with what you are doing.  Which is why you aren't seeing the files.

```
FROM        localhost:5000/lembark/busybox
MAINTAINER  lembark@wrkhors.com

VOLUME  [ "/foobar" ]

ENV     PATH /bin
WORKDIR /

ENTRYPOINT  [ "/bin/sh" ]
```

You are creating your images from an image on your pc.  What is that image from.  That could be one issue since the image you are building inherits it's base properties and O/S from that image.
The WORKDIR command sets the working directory.  Since you aren't importing anything you don't need this command. 
You are overriding the ENTRYPOINT or command that is execute each time the container is initialized by setting the ENTRYPOINT to ['/bin/sh'].  That could be why your command is not executing.  You run the container and that entry point executes.

Please see the example above.  That is a proper Dockerfile and will compile and provide the console output listed above and does exactly what you are asking.  Without seeing the Dockerfile for the image you are building your newest image from it's hard to determine exactly what other pieces you have incorrect.